# Typescript Partial type with callback doesn't work as expected

Tags: typescript

I have the following function that takes a `callback` that receives a person and need to return a `Partial` person.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}


function updatePerson(cb: (person: Person) => Partial<Person>) {
}

updatePerson(person => {
  return {
    ...person,
    notExist: true
  }
})
```

The problem is that, the user can return properties that doesn't exist on `Person`. In the above example, typescript allow to pass the `notExist` property.

Comment: There are various hacks and workarounds that may work in certain cases, but in general TypeScript is a structurally typed language, meaning you can always provide additional properties.

Comment: That's not true. It will work fine if you pass an object instead of object.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "object instead of object"?

Comment: Sorry, it should be object instead of a callback

Comment: This one the arguable decisions existing in TypeScript. You can read the explanation at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755#issuecomment-119401040

I believe there are considerations to change this behavior in upcoming versions for simple cases like the one you describe but in general TypeScript will still allow extra properties.